# Assigning Factor Levels Weights

Tags: r

I have two factor variables, gender with two levels and marital with four levels, and have corresponding frequencies in a data-frame. I want to construct a 2-way contingency table using those frequencies. Can anybody help?

```
 marital <- c("Single (M1)","Single (M1)", "Married (M2)","Married (M2)", 

"Vdowed (M3)","Vdowed (M3)", "Divorced (M4)", "Divorced (M4)")
    gender <- c("Male (S1)", "Female (S2)")
    freq <- c(129, 104, 298, 305, 13, 57, 40, 54)

    df <- data.frame(marital, gender, freq)
    View(df)
    table(df$marital,  df$gender)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tidyr::spread`:

```
library(tidyr)

df %>% spread(gender, freq)

        marital Female (S2) Male (S1)
1 Divorced (M4)          54        40
2  Married (M2)         305       298
3   Single (M1)         104       129
4   Vdowed (M3)          57        13
```

Comment: That looks nice. But can I use it like I do the elements of a table?